# How can I block further input in textarea using maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery, maxlength

I have a textarea that I want to block input on if the entered characters reaches a max-length.

I currently have a Jquery script for the textbox that calculates the characters entered and want to add something that will block input in the textarea once 150 characters are entered.

I have tried using max-length plugins in conjunction with my script but they don't seem to work. Help is appreciated.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.charCount = function(options){
        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {    
            allowed: 150,       
            warning: 25,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: '',
            container: undefined // New option, accepts a selector string
        }; 

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        function calculate(obj,$cont) {
              // $cont is the container, now passed in instead.
            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
                $cont.addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $cont.removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }
            if(available < 0){
                $cont.addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            } else {
                $cont.removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
            }
            $cont.html(options.counterText + available);
        };

        this.each(function() {
         // $container is the passed selector, or create the default container
            var $container = (options.container)
                    ? $(options.container)
                        .text(options.counterText)
                        .addClass(options.css)
                    : $('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>').insertAfter(this);
            calculate(this,$container);
            $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this,$container)});
            $(this).change(function(){calculate(this,$container)});
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried ​the maxlength attribute? That will block input once the character limit is reached.

```
<textarea maxlength='150'></textarea>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ // Won't work
<input type='text' maxlength='150' />
```

**Edit** It appears that maxlength for a textarea works in Chrome, but not in other browsers, my bad. Well, another approach would just be to monitor keydown events and if length>150, return false/preventDefault/however you want to stop the default action. You'd still want allow backspace and enter however, so monitor keycode as well.

```
$('#yourTextarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if (this.value.length > 150) 
        if ( !(e.which == '46' || e.which == '8' || e.which == '13') ) // backspace/enter/del
            e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Works on inputs but not textareas unfortunately

Comment: maxlength is not a valid textarea attribute.

Comment: Yeah, for whatever reason Chrome enforces it, which is what I tested in. Oh well, another method updated.

Comment: Not enough special characters were checked. For instance it will be impossible just to move caret at the text area after length limit will be reached.

Comment: `maxlength` is an HTML5 property for a textarea, and is not supported on Opera or IE < 9 -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: `maxlength` for `<textarea>` has [near-universal availability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=maxlength) these days.

Answer (score 6):

You're much better off not trying to prevent the user from typing in too many characters and instead showing a counter and only enforcing the character limit when the user tries to submit. The comment boxes Stack Overflow are a decent example. It's both easier technically and more importantly better for the user to do it this way: it's really irritating not to be able to type/paste/drag text into a textarea even if you know there's a character limit.

Answer (score 4):

[Textarea maxlength with Jquery](http://that-matt.com/2008/07/textarea-maxlength-with-jquery/) works OK but probably doesn't solve the issue of pasting in larger amounts of text.

PB Edit: Has since been updated [here](http://that-matt.com/2010/04/updated-textarea-maxlength-with-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: @Peter Bailey - Thanks for the link to the updated blog post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below i hope will work, remember to include jQuery library

```
<div class="texCount"></div>
<textarea class="comment"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var text_Max = 200;      
    $('.texCount').html(text_Max+'Words');

    $('.comment').keyup(function(){        
        var text_Length = $('.comment').val().length;        
        var text_Remain = text_Max - text_Length;       
        $('.texCount').html(text_Remain + 'Words');

        $('.comment').keydown(function(e){         
            if(text_Remain == 0){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the contents of the textarea if it is over 150 characters as described at http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/maxlength-for-textarea-with-jquery/. I can see some issues with copy/pasting if that brings the text over the limit though.