# Force text to fit into a specific area in a textarea input

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea that gets processed into an image. I need to force the user to type in a specific area including formatting and returns. The box should limit users from overflowing the box How can this be done?

I'm using cakephp as a framework and can therefore use html, css, php or js to accomplish this.

This is the textarea element I'm working with:

```
<textarea name="ch_text" id="ch_text" rows="8" tabindex="20"></textarea>
```

I tried adding a `cols` property, which didn't work. I tried setting `wrap="true"`, which didn't work either. Is there a way to specify a height/width property that can't be exceeded?

Comment: Please update with your actual code you have tried and your one challenge with that.

Comment: updated the question to be more specific

Comment: Have you read the related documenation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength

This is a duplicate perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578678/how-can-i-block-further-input-in-textarea-using-maxlength

Comment: There is also this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of setting the maxlength on the element and then in CSS make sure to give a height and width and set resize to none.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have usually seen this done is by enforcing a character or word limit. This can be done by using variables in the HTML code!